# Can I update my root site collection template?

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-server

Our root site collection was initially made into a developer site, which doesn't have all of the site collection features such as a Master Page. Due to changes in requirements, is there any way to use Powershell or otherwis

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint: How to change Root Site template for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25734.sharepoint-how-to-change-root-site-template.aspx